# Variables Declared in .env file in ReactJS, NextJS app are coming as Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is what I have in my .env.local file:

```
REACT_APP_API_PATH=http://localhost:3600/
```

.env.local file is at the root level.

This is how I am trying to use this variable:

```
console.log('node env' + process.env.NODE_ENV)
console.log('api path : ' + process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH)
fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH + 'auth', requestOptions)
```

Console.log 'node env' is printing development. Console.log 'api path' is printing undefined. I am using ReactJS with NextJS. I start my server with 'yarn dev' command. I have stopped and started the app multiple times.

Comment: Nextjs only exposes environment variables whose name begin with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to the browser. https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-4#new-environment-variables-support

Comment: try using dotenv: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @cbr tried this as well. Same behavior. Though, I can see these variables on server when the project is building. But they are not available on the client side/browser.

Comment: I'm using Next.js 10.0.5 version and I have the same problem. My environment variables are undefined. I have the correct naming (NEXT_PUBLIC_ENVNAME).
Any tips why they are undefined ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, had to upgrade my NextJS version to 9.4 from 9.3.5 and it started working.

Comment: Another common mistake that someone could make is forgetting to restart the server after updating `.env` file(s).

Comment: @FarazAhmad Thank you. This was my issue. I thought hot reloading would have picked up the new file, but you have to actually end the server and start it again.